# How to fix: IPA BINARY CODE ANALYSIS in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, security, app-store-connect, ipa

I got **MOBSF** security check result pdf where i found some "High" - SEVERITY issues

**like below**: I am unable to upload screen shot so i have pasted its content below. how to fix this

in below error nothing i found in code related here `sscanf , _fopen , _strlen , _stat , _printf , _memcpy` none of them i have used in code then how can I fix these errors

please guide me my app is in ***28/100 (CRITICAL RISK)***

> Binary makes use of insecure API(s)
> high
> CWE: CWE-676: Use of Potentially Dangerous Function
> OWASP Top 10: M7: Client Code Quality OWASP MASVS: MSTG-CODE-8
> The binary may contain the following insecure API(s) _sscanf , _fopen , _strlen , _stat , _printf , _memcpy

> Binary makes use of malloc function
> high
> CWE: CWE-789: Uncontrolled Memory Allocation
> OWASP Top 10: M7: Client Code Quality OWASP MASVS: MSTG-CODE-8
> The binary may use _malloc function instead of calloc